# In the real analytic category, are the fibers of a proper submersion isomorphic?

Tags: differential-topology, fibre-bundles, real-analytic-structures

Ehresmann's theorem says that a proper smooth submersion is a fiber bundle. The proofs I know rely on the existence of connections locally on the base, and this is furnished by partitions of unity.

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/56737/69037) gives a counterexample in the holomorphic category which is probably classic (elliptic curves), but I don't know any of the story.

I am wondering about the real analytic category. Are the fibers of a proper real analytic submersion isomorphic? If not, will it be locally trivial (in the real analytic category) when they are isomorphic, as in the linked question?

Comment: The question in the title is just the opposite than the question in the body of the question. I suggest an edit for the coherence's sake.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exists an analytic Riemann metric on a real-analytic manifold, which follows from embeddability of real analytic manifolds (see  The Analytic Embedding of Abstract Real-Analytic Manifolds Charles B. Morrey, Jr.) - maybe can also be proved easier.

So, you can probably just take orthogonal connection.

Comment: So, the answer to the question *in the title* is **yes**, right?

Comment: Dear @Lev, I just found [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249055/ehresmanns-theorem-over-the-p-adics/249334#comment612379_249055) which remarks the some references assert Ehresmann is false in the real analytic category. Just out of curiosity, have you ever stumbled upon such a claim?

Comment: Dear @Lev, your answer gives a connection on the tangent bundle of an analytic manifold, but how can it be used to obtain a connection on an analytic submersion?

Comment: Arrow, considering this comment, I wonder. I hadn't seen such claims, and I have a feeling that Ehresmann should be true in analytic setting from reasons mentioned above. The construction of the connection is similar to the smooth case - we need to chose analytic distribution which is transverse to fibers. Lets just choose it to be orthogonal (so it is even easier than what you've wrote in your answer, I suppose I should've made the proof more clear).

Comment: Dear @LevSoukhanov, I would really appreciate some additional details since I don't see how to construct such an analytic connection *on the submersion*. (I would like to circumvent the tubular neighborhood proof of Ehresmann sketched in my answer, which feels like transparent to me.)

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you mean by connection on a submersion? For me the connection is the distribution transverse to the fibers.

I do not really understand where the concern comes from.

Comment: Dear Arrow, maybe I understood where the concern comes from. That way we get the connection, but not a flat one. It still allows to construct trivialisation, say, by moving all the fibers along this connection to the origin on the base along the straight lines.

Comment: Dear @LevSoukhanov, I don't know what bothered me when I wrote my last comment, but I'll delete it in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ehresmann's theorem does hold in the real-analytic category. A proof via tubular neighborhoods can be repeated in the real-analytic context since it makes no use of partitions of unity. Here's a sketch.

By Lev's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/333981/69037), a real-analytic manifold admits a real-analytic embedding into Euclidean space with its standard real-analytic structure. I think this implies a real-analytic manifold admits a real-analytic Riemannian metric.

The exponential map of this metric is also real-analytic (as a solution to analytic ODE), so an analytically embedded submanifold admits a real-analytic tubular neighborhood. We may then repeat [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112665/223002) of Ehresmann's theorem using tubular neighborhoods.

*Remark.* [This comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249055/ehresmanns-theorem-over-the-p-adics/249334#comment612379_249055) along with several other places in the literature assert Ehresmann's theorem fails in the real-analytic category but provide no examples.